# Searching for a secure logout approach in my backend

Tags: php, security, backend

I am currently involved in a small project and we try to point out a logout method/algorithm. It's our first time developing a backend and we wonder if it is enough to transmit the session token encrypted so it is ensured, that nobody else than the legitimate person knows the token. And on logout we simply send the token to revoke, and the token will be revoked in private storage. Is that a secure approach or are there any other state of the art methods we should implement? Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for additional encryption, let HTTPS do its job. Simply call `session_destroy();` that's all. You must make sure the PHPSESSID cookie has the `httpOnly` and `Secure` flags enabled though.

Comment: Unfortunatly we decided on programming that software partially encrypted for the case, that the user wants to use a free hosting provider without ssl support. So encryption should be in that case important, shouldn't it? We are not sure whether to use such sessions build in php. Is it possible to trigger a such session creation from android or something similar too? Just for the case, that we want to develop an android app lateron as well. At the moment we thougt of managing sessions by ourself with our own private storage.

Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Encryption is indeed important, but you shouldn't try to make your own crypto, just use state of the art standards. I highly doubt that nowadays there exist hosting providers that do not provide TLS support, especially since Let's Encrypt arrival. Of course it depends on the purpose. If you want to do your own encryption to learn how it works, then go ahead, but if you plan to do anything serious, please let the people who **really** know what they do handle that for you. Android has nothing to do with that, it's just a frontend like any other.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but I guess you're planning to use HTTP for communications right ? You can use a custom private storage for android if you want to, but in my opinion you should use the PHPSESSID cookie anyway, or you'll get into more trouble than you probably want to.

Comment: Also, storing the session ID in the local storage of your browser using javascript is a really bad idea. PHPSESSIDs should be httpOnly cookies, meaning they shouldn't be accessable through javascript. This is a security measure to prevent XSS attacks from stealing the ID.

Comment: What do you think about libsodium? It seems to be part of php since 7.4 or something like that. We played around with that library. Do you think it would be okay to use this encryption in an application with moderate critical data? Thank you for that helpful feedback. :)

Comment: Okay. And what is about that cool new localStorage approach in modern browsers? Because we want the application to live since the session is outdated (maybe a month or something like that) or the session was revoked manually. Is that possible with PHPSESSID cookie? Do you maybe have some useful links to begin with? That would be very nice. And again thank you very much for the help. :)

Comment: I don't know libsodium, never used it. I hate PHP to be honest. What I know for sure however is that using cool crypto library won't protect you from anything if you don't know how to do it correctly. Cryptography is not magic, just because you use it doesn't mean you're safe. It's very easy to feel secure, mess up completely, and do nothing useful security-wise. For example do you have any clue what asymmetric and symmetric cryptography are ? If you want advice regarding cryptography I will need more context about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Browsers' local storage is very useful if you want to store large amount of data, but it's not of any use to store something as small as a session id (+ [it's not secure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)). On the client-side, PHP session IDs only consists of a single cookie, and like any other cookie, you can define its lifespan to say how long it will remain valid. Regarding manual revocation, I don't how to do it but I'm pretty sure it's possible. On the server side PHP sessions are simple files you could delete if you want to.